# Query to UserRecordAccess for multiple record ids returns unpredictable results

Tags: soql, query

I am using the query editor.
Consider the following query:

```
SELECT RecordId, HasDeleteAccess FROM UserRecordAccess
WHERE UserId = '005J0000006QnWhIAK'
AND RecordId IN ('00UJ000000AZUulMAH','00UJ000000AZUvRMAX')
```

When using multiple record ids the query returns wrong results:

```
00UJ000000AZUulMAH, HasDeleteAccess, false
00UJ000000AZUvRMAX, HasDeleteAccess, false
```

If I run the same query run with one recordId at a time (even while still using the `IN` operator) it returns `true` for both records.

Comment: Just try to do like this SELECT RecordId, HasDeleteAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE RecordId IN ('00UJ000000AZUulMAH','00UJ000000AZUvRMAX') AND UserId = '005J0000006QnWhIAK'

Comment: Apart from inverting the 2 WHERE params, what difference should it make? Anyway I had already tried without success.

Comment: Yeah I can reproduce this behavior. Looks like a bug. There doesn't yet appear to be a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?keywords=UserRecordAccess) for it. You should log a case.

Comment: I have run into this issue as well, really hope somebody comes up with a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. All the code examples I found on Internet were using the method that was valid before API version 30.

In the documentation I've found a new way of receiving info about UserRecordAccess:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm

Following the Docs your code should call this query:

```
SELECT Id, UserRecordAccess.HasDeleteAccess 
FROM YourObjectName__c
WHERE Id IN ('00UJ000000AZUulMAH','00UJ000000AZUvRMAX')
```

Comment: Nice observation. Unfortunately the query doesn't work with all objects. I needed to execute it on `Event` ids but `Event` is not contemplated.